# switching two views causes crash

Tags: iphone, memory-management

```
XYZAppDelegate *appdelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
CSelectorViewController *cPrice=[[CSelectorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CSelectorViewController" bundle:nil];
[cPrice.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 480)];
[appdelegate.window addSubview:cPrice.view];

[self applyAnimation];
[cPrice release];
```

i am adding a view like this,not using navigationcontroller,since i have to switch two views top-bottom also.but when i am giving the [cPrice release];  the app crashes. but when i am not giving it in code... the static analyser is showing a warning..what is the right way to do this?

```
-(void)applyAnimation
{
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    XYZAppDelegate *appdelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[appdelegate.window layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"slideLeft"];
}
```

Comment: Crashes with what error??  What's in the console?

Comment: message sent to deallocated instance... i know its due to memory problem ,just wanted to know whats the right way to do it ..without memory leak

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the `view` of cPrice to the window as a subview (which will implicitly retain the view), but you do nothing to preserve cPrice itself.  You should make it a retained property or some such.